# Make electron window able to receive click event when above keynote app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am working on electron app where i open a child window which i want to be above all the windows (not above fullscreen windows though), I managed to do it by using

```
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "screen-saver");
```

It now stays on top of all other open apps and keynote app presentation mode, i want user to be able to click buttons inside my window but now the issue is as soon as user clicks on button or just window in my child window, keynote window minimizes (as focus shifts to my window).

**What i tried** : I tried almost all available window option given in electron docs with different variations, I also tried playing with modals, but obviously modals stay in window itself, i want to keep main app minimized and keep child window on top of other apps. I also found `electron-modal` package, but that also behaves same.

**working example** 
I was trying different application to check is any other application is able to do it, and i found that zoom app window (in screen share mode) is able to stay on top of keynote app and you can click buttons inside that app, you can move window, and keynote app keeps running in the background with no issues. I am trying to achieve exactly same behaviour.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you won't be able to recreate with electron currently, except through a native node module that manipulates your window related OS flags.

You can follow this issue on the Electron repository, since the flags introduced there should resolve your issue, or at least give you a point of entry to make your own PR or node_module.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10078

Comment: I have already gone through that issue, that issue is more about keeping window on top over other fullscreen apps, I want my child window to be on top of only keynote and should be able to receive clicks without closing keynote. Do you think above solution solve my problem ?

Comment: Same window flag as far as i know, as stated there is no way of doing this without patching electron.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, at the moment I don't have other potential solution in mind so I guess I have to give it a try. thanks friend.

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me just wondering if you figured out something, I have the same issue with an electron app minimizing the keynote

Comment: @davekr: No I am still searching for the solution. If you find, please let me know also.

Comment: Have anyone found answer ? I need help.